# Is it still possible to create IFrame post?

Tags: facebook, iframe

I want to be able to post iframe on user's page, i.e. basically completely custom post with its own html markup and its own javascript. Something like when you post youtube/vimeo or coub video, they have their own players.

It seems to be possible just judging from the fact that there are apps exist which allow you to do it and there are also some guides on how to create "iframe app", but those guides seems to be pretty outdated.

I could not find anything about that in facebook docs. Canvas seems to be the closest one, but it's a page outside of user's timeline and I need it to be embedded in the timeline, like a post which can be shared, liked etc.

Any pointers to docs would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: No it is not possible

Comment: if it's not possible then how come there are app which do it? like for example coub.com. they have their own player which sits directly in user's timeline and plays those videos.

Comment: Most likely it is a flash player that anyone can do. Or it is an HTML5 player that a few sites are testing right now.